# Works in Console but not in .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add width and height attributes to my images; the jQuery I used works in the console but not in the linked .js file. I have tried this and it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.media-box-image').each(function () {

        var $width = $('.media-box-image').width();
        var $height = $('.media-box-image').height();
        var $this = $(this).find('img');

        $this.attr('width', $width);
        $this.attr('height', $height);
    });
});
```

I also tried this but it also didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.media-box-image').each().on('load', function () {

        var $width = $('.media-box-image').width();
        var $height = $('.media-box-image').height();
        var $this = $(this).find('img');

        $this.attr('width', $width);
        $this.attr('height', $height);
    });
});
```

I checked the console but everything seems to be fine. What else can I do?

Comment: `ready` will fire when the DOM is ready. You need `window`'s `load` event, so that the callback will be fired when all the images are completely loaded.

Comment: document.ready, doesnt really mean that the images are loaded. You might want to use load, as mentioned above. Care to share, a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered my own question: I did the following and it works perfectly

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // Run code
    $('.media-box-image').each(function () {
        var $width = $('.media-box-image').width();
        var $height = $('.media-box-image').height();
        var $this = $(this).find('img');

        $this.attr('width', $width);
        $this.attr('height', $height);
    });
});
```

Comment: And you should use `$(this)` inside the `each` instead of `$('.media-box-image')`.

Answer (score 3):

When the document ready callback executes during the initial page load cycle, the page will not have finished loading image data.

Because there's no image data, the images have neither widths nor heights.

Use `$(window).on('load'...)` instead of `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot I realized this shortly after I posted the question. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks a lot man for your answer. Already spend more than 5 hours behind this.

Answer (score 1):

You make sure if your `<script>` tag is the end of your `<body>`. Which solved the same problem for me.

```
<body>
<!--your HTML-->
<script src="..."></script>
</body>
```